# Does multi cores machines helps in fast processing with Multithreading?

Tags: java, multithreading, multicore

I'm getting confused with multiple threads execution within in multiple cores of a machine.

For example, I've a method which is bulding a 100 story building.

```
synchronized buildingStories(){

}
```

To complete building faster, I decide to use 4 workers (threads). Lets say when T1 will build a floor1 and T2 will build floor2 and so on.

So once T1 acquired a lock on `buildingStories` , T2 wont be able to acquire lock and do his build until T1 release it. Even machine is mutli core and other threads or workers have to be in queue until shared resource is free, how multi threading increasing the performance ? At the end Thread have to wait until its turn come and run to core to process it.

Its very naive quesion, but suggestion would be appreciated to understand.

Comment: It helps in situations where several tasks can work independently without synchronization.

Comment: Yes, multiple cores help, but not if the entire process blocks and only one thread can execute at a time.  That obviously does nothing to complete faster.  What you are after is parallelism, and it's not automatic when using multiple threads.  Look up [Amdahl's Law.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law)

Comment: If you're just running threads in series, you don't need threads; you can just call each method and let them block.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. If two threads lock the same object, then one of the threads will block, which doesn't help with performance. If on the other hand, the two threads can run completely independently of each other, then there is a huge performance gain.